# how many days have passed since Friday - Perl Variable

Tags: perl

I'm trying to calculate the number of days that have passed since last Friday?

For example, today is 7/19/2022, and last Friday was 7/15/2022 therefore, four days have passed.
7/19/2022 - 7/15/2022 = **4 days**

I need this to update every day to just display # of days.

Can someone help me write this out to assign to a variable?

Thank you in advance!!! (new to coding)

Comment: Had a look around [CPAN](https://www.cpan.org)?

Comment: You just need the `localtime` builtin and two math operations to find out how many days it has been since Friday.

Comment: I need this to be dynamic to always look for the previous Friday's date and compare it to today's date to return # of days.

Comment: And to do that, you just need the `localtime` builtin and two math operations

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [localtime](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/localtime) and simple modular arithmetic:

```
( (localtime)[6] - 5 ) % 7
```

( (current day index) - (friday day index) ) mod (days in a week)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Date::Calc` Module. Here is the one liner version.

```
perl -E 'use Date::Calc qw(:all); say Delta_Days(2022,7,15, 2022,7,19,)'
```